# Sending Ctrl+C to process started with exec

Tags: windows, go

I'm trying to send a CTRL-C event to a java process started with exec.

```
cmd := exec.Command("javaw", "-cp", "burst.jar;conf", "brs.Burst") 
cmd.Dir = burstCmdPath
cmd.Env = append(os.Environ())
err = cmd.Start()
...
cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGINT)
```

Unfortunately, the SIGINT-signal does not work on windows.
I do not want to KILL the process. I just want to close it gracefully with CTRL-C.

I tried several things:

1. Calling taskkill: Process does only react to forced kill.
2. Using win32-API:

   ```
   ...
   d, err := syscall.LoadDLL("kernel32.dll")               
   p, e := d.FindProc("GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent")
   r, _, e := p.Call(syscall.CTRL_C_EVENT, uintptr(cmd.Process.Pid))
   if r == 0 {
       fmt.Print("GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent: %v\n", e)
   }
   ...
   ```

   Does not throw any errors, but does not work either.

If you open burst.jar inside a shell, you can just press CTRL+C to signal a shutdown, but why not with exec? 
Any ideas?

Comment: A process can send Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break to a process *group* (not necessarily an individual process) only if the sending process is attached to the same console (i.e. conhost.exe instance). The simplest group is 0, which sends the event to all processes attached to the console, including the sender (which must ignore the event). If a process is the lead of a group (i.e. created with the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`), by default it has Ctrl+C completely disabled (no handler is called), unless manually enabled. Ctrl+Break can't be ignored in the same way, so it's the more reliable of the two.

Comment: If the parent is a GUI process without a console, it can easily attach to the child's console via `AttachConsole`. Or it can preallocate its own console via `AllocConsole` and have the child inherit it. If the parent and child have a different console, it's more complicated since the parent will have to start a process such as cmd.exe to keep its console referenced, then use `FreeConsole` and `AttachConsole` twice in order to temporarily attach to the child's console and then attach back to its original console.

Comment: "Interrupt is not implemented on Windows; using it with os.Process.Signal will return an error." https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Signal